# Centering rows in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} [ht]
\caption{caption}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1\textwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
\toprule 
Method & Accuracy & Critical Value \\
\midrule
Method A where \\ method B failed & 55.00\% & 70.00\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{mdfmofail}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This comes out with a table that looks good except the 55 and 70 are in line with the bottom line.

Ideally, I would like them more centred with the first entry (Method A \ where B failed)

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please always provide complete small document which we can copy and compile on our computers! column of type `c` doesn't allow multi lines text in cells. you should use  `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}` from package `array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm guessing that you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [ht]
    \centering
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\raggedright}m{31mm} c c @{}}                   % <---
\toprule
Method & Accuracy & Critical Value \\
\midrule
Method A where method B failed & 55.00\% & 70.00\% \\  % <---
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{mdfmofail}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**note:** `c` column doesn't allow multi lines text in cells. you should use `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}` (as in mwe above) from package array. if you like to have horizontally centered text in the first column, than you use `>{\centering}m{3cm}`.

Comment: Yes, that looks great! Thank you. Just out of curiosity how did you get the 30mm number? Did you just eyeball it? Also is it possible to center the first column as well?

Comment: @Carl Zarko is very expert in table :-) Apparently, he also uses crystal balls :-)

Comment: @Carl, by experiences :-). you can count number of letters in the longest line of cell's text and than use for example `m{7em}`, where `em` is width of letter `M`. in your case you have  14 letters, but all (except are shorter than M (about 1/2 of `em`), so estimated width of `7em` seems to be good value